# Finding the intersection of matching elements in multiples lists and returning the indicies

Tags: python

so I'm having a problem with one of my programs. I have a few lists and they are all the same length. The lists are combinations of an original list. The thing I need is the index where a specific element is repeated multiple times. For example:

```
a = ["x","t","y"]
b = ["t","x","y"]
c = ["t","t","y"]
```

I want it to turn 2.

Answer (score 1):

Something to get you started:

```
In [7]: for i, n in enumerate(zip(a,b,c)): print n, i
('x', 't', 't') 0
('t', 'x', 't') 1
('y', 'y', 'y') 2
```

Comment: I like answers like these to questions like these. Try to nudge the OP in the right direction without doing *everything* for them. I am not sure if others will agree with me, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
map(lambda x: x.count(x[0]) == len(x), zip(*[a, b, c])).index(True)
```

`x.count(x[0]) == len(x)` is much faster than `len(set(x)) == 1`

For larger sub lists > 20 elements `lambda x: x == len(x)*[x[0]]` is even faster:

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
>>> a = ["x","t","y"]
>>> b = ["t","x","y"]
>>> c = ["t","t","y"]
>>> lis = [a, b, c]
>>> next( i for i,x in enumerate(zip(*lis)) if len(set(x)) == 1)
2
```

`zip(*lis)` unzips the list and you get:

```
>>> lis = [a, b, c]
>>> zip(*lis)
[('x', 't', 't'), ('t', 'x', 't'), ('y', 'y', 'y')]
```

Now we can iterate over each item of this new list and check at what index all items are equal. A `set` is the best way to check that.

```
>>> set(('y', 'y', 'y'))
set(['y'])               #length is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

one-liner:

```
filter(lambda x : a[x] == b[x] and a[x] == c[x], range(len(a)))
```

Note, that will return a list with the indexes where all elements match, so you'll actually get `[2]`, not `2` as the result.

If you just want the integer value (not a list):

```
idxs = filter(lambda x : a[x] == b[x] and a[x] == c[x], range(len(a)))
result = idxs[0] if idxs else None
```

Comment: `filter(lambda x : a[x] == b[x] and a[x] == c[x], range(len(a)))[0]`

Comment: @Ashwini - that gets the value as an int, but will crap out if there are no matches.  I'll edit my answer.